# process next event one after previous event ended

Tags: node.js, imap, control-flow

I'm using node-imap module for fetching mails and my code is

```
var Imap = require('imap'),
    request = require('request');

var imap = new Imap();
/** Code for connecting to mail server **/

var fetch = imap.fetch([1,2,3]);

fetch.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {

  msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {  

    stream.on('end', function() {
      request('http://httpbin.org/ip', function(error, response, body){
        console.log(response.statusCode);
      });
    });

  });

}
```

but if multiple message exists the request will be finished on last, i want to every message and request ended and go to the next message, how to handle this with node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but if multiple message exists the request will be finished on last

That is not what would happen. The messages are processed **asynchronously**, as with the requests. It may appear so since messages are processed as fast as possible, along with the requests. Node will not "wait" for the entire event to finish before beginning on another one.

Is it crucial that the messages get processed in serial order? If so, check out the async library.

Comment: Yes the order of request is critical, i look at the async module but, could not figure out how to handle this with async

Comment: could you give me solution for my problem with async?

Comment: Nope. i'll help you out, but I won't do your job for you. Using queue, just queue up a function with the request after each message is done reading.

Comment: its did not worked with request, i put request code inside task worker function but the order of response is not right, before you answer be sure your way work please

Comment: You queued too late. You need to do it earlier before msg.on, since the stream may end at different times. Also, this won't work unless the message on event comes in order from imap.